# How can i build a project Ruby in Xcode?

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm

I have a question regarding Ruby on Mac. When i bulid the project, there is an error as follows:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- plist (LoadError)

from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from .../app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iphone.build/Script-2095E433129114D900424894.sh:3
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Xcode 4.3.3 is installed on my computer, which use Mac OS X 10.7.4, and i installed ruby 1.9.3 with rvm and set ruby 1.9.3 as default:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3

Using ../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194

$ ruby -v

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

Someone knows the solution to solve this?

Comment: Hi, I had exactly the same problem. I followed this tutorial : http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/ and it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's that mean i should uninstall Xcode, rvm, ruby and reinstall them?

Comment: That's what I had to do. Wait for other answers, maybe there's another solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, the tutorial is very useful, if i asked this question a litter earlier, everything should be change.

Comment: I haven't used Xcode before but I've read almost universally bad things. Even the reviews on the mac app store are terrible. Would it not perhaps be better to spend time learning a new (more Ruby friendly) tool?

Comment: check out [aptana studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) its free and awesome. And I like using [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) to manage ruby versions and update

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the command-line tools in Xcode? I think you open Xcode, go to preferences and in there somewhere, you can install command line utilities. You might need to recompile your rvm ruby afterwards.